# select and count number of entries at the start and end of day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically i want to know that when the store is open and closed how many employees are there the details are as follow

```
EmployeeID | IN and OUT Time         | Type       | InOut ID | Comments    |
---------- | ----------------------- |------------| ---------|-------------|
12961        2017-04-24 08:07:00.000    Punch In      1        Store Open
12680        2017-04-24 08:07:00.000    Punch In      2
12662        2017-04-24 08:07:00.000    Punch In      3
12683        2017-04-24 08:27:00.000    Punch In      4        
12864        2017-04-24 08:42:00.000    Punch In      5
12681        2017-04-24 10:03:00.000    Punch In      6
-1           2017-04-24 13:33:00.000    Punch In      7
12662        2017-04-24 18:00:00.000    Punch Out     8
12683        2017-04-24 18:00:00.000    Punch Out     9
12864        2017-04-24 18:35:00.000    Punch Out     10 
12681        2017-04-24 22:00:00.000    Punch Out     11
12960        2017-04-24 22:00:00.000    Punch Out     12 
12959        2017-04-24 22:00:00.000    Punch Out     13 
-1           2017-04-24 22:00:00.000    Punch Out     14        Store Close
```

**Result:**

```
Header               | Header
-------------------- | ------
No. Of Emp At Open   | 3 
No. Of Emp At Close  | 4
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your result. And also it is not clear on what condition it is decided that employee is in the store when store is opened and when it is closed.

Comment: Consider a employee Punch In at `2017-04-24 08:42:00.000` and he did not `punch Out` on or before `2017-04-24 22:00:00.000`. In that case should the employee be counted for `No. Of Emp At Close`

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using. `Mysql` or `Sql Server`

Comment: How are they all able to punch at the exact same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to find whether the employee is still in office or not. Then you can count the no:of employees at office and out of office from the output of this query.

```
SELECT in.EmployeeID , 
       CASE WHEN out.EmployeeID IS NULL 
             THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS Still_In_Office                   
FROM Employee in
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee out ON in.EmployeeID  = out.EmployeeID 
                                AND out.Type = "Punch Out"
WHERE in.Type = "Punch In"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'No. Of Emp At Open',count([IN and OUT Time]) from Employee where [IN and OUT Time] in (select [IN and OUT Time] from Employee where Comments= 'Store Open') group by [IN and OUT Time]union all select 'No. Of Emp At Close', count([IN and OUT Time]) from Employee where [IN and OUT Time] in (select [IN and OUT Time] from Employee where Comments= 'Store Close') group by [IN and OUT Time]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
SELECT
T.IN_OUT_TYPE AS Header1
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableABC ABC WHERE ABC.IN_and_OUT_ Time = T.IN_and_OUT_ Time) AS Header2
FROM
(
SELECT 
'No. Of Emp At Open' AS IN_OUT_TYPE
IN_and_OUT_ Time
FROM tableABC
WHERE Comments = 'Store Open'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
'No. Of Emp At Close' AS IN_OUT_TYPE
IN_and_OUT_ Time
FROM tableABC
WHERE Comments = 'Store Close'
) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select [IN and OUT Time],count(*) from table 
where  [IN and OUT Time] in(select [IN and OUT Time] from table 
where Comments  in('Store Open','Store Close'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not explained properly.
what is correct Intime including grace ?

```
declare @CorrectInTimeIncludingGrace datetime='8:15'
declare @CorrectOutTimeIncludingGrace datetime='22:00'
declare @AttendanceDate datetime='2017-04-24'
declare @AttendanceInDate datetime
declare @AttendanceOutDate datetime
set @AttendanceInDate=dateadd(minute,datepart(minute,@CorrectInTimeIncludingGrace)
, dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,@CorrectInTimeIncludingGrace), @AttendanceDate))

set @AttendanceOutDate=dateadd(minute,datepart(minute,@CorrectOutTimeIncludingGrace)
, dateadd(hour,datepart(hour,@CorrectOutTimeIncludingGrace), @AttendanceDate))

declare @t table(EmployeeID int,IN_OUT dateTime, Type varchar(20),InOutID int, Comments varchar(40))
insert into @t  VALUES 
(12961,'2017-04-24 08:07:00.000', 'Punch In' ,  1 ,'Store Open')
,(12680,'2017-04-24 08:07:00.000','Punch In', 2 ,  null)
,(12662,'2017-04-24 08:07:00.000','Punch In', 3 ,  null)
,(12683,'2017-04-24 08:27:00.000','Punch In', 4  ,  null)
,(12864,'2017-04-24 08:42:00.000','Punch In', 5 ,  null)
,(12681,'2017-04-24 10:03:00.000','Punch In', 6 ,  null)
,(-1   ,'2017-04-24 13:33:00.000','Punch In', 7 ,  null)
,(12662,'2017-04-24 18:00:00.000','Punch Out', 8    ,  null)
,(12683,'2017-04-24 18:00:00.000','Punch Out', 9    ,  null)
,(12864,'2017-04-24 18:35:00.000','Punch Out', 10,  null)
,(12681,'2017-04-24 22:00:00.000','Punch Out', 11,  null)
,(12960,'2017-04-24 22:00:00.000','Punch Out', 12,  null)
,(12959,'2017-04-24 22:00:00.000','Punch Out', 13,  null)
,(-1   ,'2017-04-24 22:00:00.000','Punch Out', 14, 'Store Close')

select 'No. Of Emp At Open' as Header, count(*)HeaderCount
from @t where
IN_OUT<= @AttendanceInDate
union ALL
select 'No. Of Emp At Close' , count(*)
from @t where
IN_OUT>= @AttendanceOutDate
```